# Mysql stuck with hundreeds of sleep process after dump import

Tags: mysql

So I imported this database dump from a 10.2.11-MariaDB webserver into my local machine Mysql 5.7 (supposedly compatible with each other ?)

The dump seems to import fine, but once imported, any connection to any of my localhost websites that connect to any database triggers the creations of many "sleep" processes on the imported Database to the point of saturation.
I get 'too many connections' errors when I do queries in MYSQL cli and any of my local websites that use MYSQL timeout when I try to load a page...

Everything comes back to order if I delete the imported database (I can still use command lines to DELETE the DB).

Any Idea on how to solve this (I need to get this DB on my localhost) ?

Answer (score -1):

What's to solve? If you have connections and they're not doing anything, they're sleeping. These don't use a whole lot of resources, especially not CPU cycles, so they can be ignored.

If you want to know *why* you have so many connections, look at the IP and port associated with one of them, then look on that machine with a tool like `lsof` to see which process is using that port.

Comment: I've edited the question with some precisions, I get 'too many connections' so I believe sleep processes saturate MySQL  max connections, they seems to be created in an infinite loop. What's really strange is that these sleep processes get created when I load a page even if the website use a diferente database !

Comment: It might be that you have a process that opens a connection and does not properly close it or return it to a connection pool when done. This is probably unrelated to your dump/restore procedure.

Comment: I spent days on this before asking here, I am positivly certain importing this  particular db triggers it while droping it restore normal behavior. 
I know it makes no sense...

Comment: Dropping it could cause any processes that normally "leak" database connections to fail, error out, rather than consume all these resources. You need to track down what's creating those connections because the restore process is not it.